# What is the author trying to say?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

while reading *The Art of Problem Solving: Volume 1*, I came across this proof in chapter 19 that a reflection of a circle is a congruent circle:

"Let the original oenter be $O$, the radius of the circle be $r$, and the reflection of $O$ be $O'$. If the point $P$ is on the original circle, then $OP=r$. The image of $OP$ is $O'P'$, where $P'$ is the image of $P$, so $O'P'=r$ because lengths are preserved. Thus the image of $P$ is on a circle of radius $r$.

Are we done? No. For all we know at this point, the image of a circle could be a *semicircle*."

I'm a little confused, how could reflecting a circle produce a semicircle ? I thought reflections preserve shape and distance ?

Comment: Please give more context. Anyway, it seems the things proved so far enables to conclude only  that the reflected image is contained in a circle. So we still need to prove that it will be the whole circle.

Comment: I added the whole proof.

Comment: Ok. No, the reflection of a circle is always a circle. The sentence is on half way while proving it.  Does that clarify it?

Comment: Ohh lol I see, thanks!

Comment: The author might as well said that the  image could be an arc of a circle of the same radius.